# Reorder bindable listview by drag and drop using UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, drag-and-drop, uwp

I'm trying to reorder `ListView`  by drag and drop,it work with me while am using static items, but when I bind the data using *itemsSorce* the drag work fine but i can't drop the item this is my code

C#:

```
lstSrvMenu.ItemsSource = Menue.MainItems.Where(m => int.Parse(m.GroupID) > 0);
```

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="lstSrvMenu" Margin="0,40,0,0" AllowDrop="True" CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True" IsSwipeEnabled="true">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupTDesc}" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when I bind the data using itemsSorce the drag work fine but i can't drop the item this is my code.

The problem is the type of  `ListView` `ItemSourse`  is not [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.7) . When you drag item completely, the sorting of the data source does not change, and the interface will not change accordingly. For your requirement, you could use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List<>`.

**Example**

```
var list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    list.Add(i.ToString() + "Template");
}
lstSrvMenu.ItemsSource = list;
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to add this drag and drop functionality to a MasterDeatilView ?(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.controls.masterdetailsview)