# UWP ListView Why Can't I re-order the list

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to re-order my ListView Items. I have them bound to an ObservableCollection and I am using prism.
I must be missing something I've followed some tutorials http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/06/walkthrough-reordering-items-in.html but I can't get it to work. I have set the required properties

```
AllowDrop="True"
ReorderMode="Enabled"
CanDragItems="True"
```

When I try to re-order using the mouse I get the little prohibited symbol?

Here is my XAML:

```
<Grid Margin="1,1,1,1" Background="WhiteSmoke">
    <StackPanel Background="Aquamarine">
        <ListView
            AllowDrop="True"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            CanDragItems="True"
            Width="200"
            Height="200"
            Margin="5"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="5"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.People, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ReorderMode="Enabled"
            SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:Person">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{x:Bind Age}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Below link may help            
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522556/reorder-bindable-listview-by-drag-and-drop-using-uwp

Answer (score 1):

The reason I could not re-order the item is due to this property.

```
       CanReorderItems="True"
```

Not to be confused with this property.

```
  ReorderMode="Enabled"
```